# Akavache init and registering a constant in Prism for DI

Tags: prism, akavache

I am using Akavache and would like to register the constant BlobCache.LocalMachine such that when I inject IBlobCache in the constructor of my viewmodels it just picks it up.

I believe the Ninject equivalent is:

```
Bind<Akavache.IBlobCache>().ToConstant(Akavache.BlobCache.LocalMachine);
```

What I want to do:

```
readonly IBlobCache _cache;
// ...
public MainViewModel(INavService navService, IBlobCache cache)
    : base (navService)
{
    _cache = cache;
}
```

Finally, I am seeing conflicting information on what to do when I 'logout' of my app. Is the correct sequence:

```
_cache.Shutdown()
```

or

```
_cache.InvalidateAll()
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for `RegisterInstance`:

```
containerRegistry.RegisterInstance<Akavache.IBlobCache>( Akavache.BlobCache.LocalMachine );
```

This will make the container inject `LocalMachine` (at the time of registration) whenever `IBlobCache` is needed.

Comment: That is what I thought, but my intellisense gives me the message 'IBlobCache is the core interface on which Akavache is built, it is an interface describing an asynchronous persistent key-value store. Type argument specification is redundant', and suggests to remove <IBlobCache> ...so then I don't understand how injecting IBlobCache in the constructore would know to use localmachine.

Comment: Of course, if `LocalMachine` is of type `IBlobCache`, then the generic argument is redundant... it's not _wrong_ either, though.

Comment: Interesting, I have always paired the Interface with the Service so this is def new to me. Learn something new every day.